# Buildbot access restriction configuration

Tags: configuration, authentication, build-server

I'm trying to install [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/) so I can perform automatic stuff like building my latex documents and running unit tests. I wan't it to be available online, so I'm doing it on a VPS (Digital Ocean). I've installed and the web interface is up and the slave is connected.

When I've tried to add some restrictions I was able to use a pair login/password already in the sample config file. But the projects and tabs still show up for a no logged user.

I've also tried to use a htpasswd file with the following snippet:

```
authz_cfg=authz.Authz(
# change any of these to True to enable; see the manual for more
# options
auth=auth.HTPasswdAuth("/root/buildbot/bb-master/htpasswd"),
gracefulShutdown = False,
forceBuild = 'auth', # use this to test your slave once it is set up
forceAllBuilds = 'auth',  # ..or this
pingBuilder = False,
stopBuild = False,
stopAllBuilds = False,
cancelPendingBuild = False,
```

)

How do I config BuildBot os hide all content and only show up after authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `view='auth'` to the Authz call.

```
authz_cfg=authz.Authz(
    auth=auth.HTPasswdAuth("/root/buildbot/bb-master/htpasswd"),
    view='auth'
)
```